# Distinct/Unique entries in CountIfs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a countIFS in excel referencing a DATE(B), SITE(G) and Location(F), which gives me a current result of 4 which is 4 lines of data which is correct.

However I want to additionally count the number of distinct jobs (C) within this data of which there is 2. (3 lines for 1 job and 1 line for the 2nd)

Anyone got any insight to how I can achieve this?

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,'Daily Man Hours'!E3,CognosData!F:F,'Daily Man Hours'!E4,CognosData!G:G,"GATE")
```

[image: Reference per above]

Comment: Can you please add a visual of your dataset? Right now it's difficult to understand what it looks like.

Comment: thanks Totsie i uploaded a reference. hopefuly that provides more insight.i'm trying to count the Unique Jobs in C dependant on B being a certain Date and also the Site/Location being specified as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find uniques then you can use formula like below.

```
    =SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(CognosData!B:B='Daily Man Hours'!E3,IF(CognosData!F:F='Daily Man Hours'!E4,IF(CognosData!G:G="GATE",CognosData!C:C,0),0),0),IF(CognosData!B:B='Daily Man Hours'!E3,IF(CognosData!F:F='Daily Man Hours'!E4,IF(CognosData!G:G="GATE",CognosData!C:C,-1),-1),-1))>0))
```

**Note: This is Array formula so it should be committed by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER simultaneously. If done correctly then Excel will surround the formula with {} symbols.**

Caution: You are using complete column references (*CognosData!B:B*) which may slow down your workbook significantly. Use finite number(*CognosData!B1:B10000*) so as to limit calculation overload.